# Вывод информации о процессе

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Допустим есть процесс firefox(pid 5059)
Как вывести с помощью ps владельца этого процесса, аргументы с которыми был запущен этот процесс, группу владельца этого процесса и т.д.

ps -eo user, ? , ? | grep firefox

Comment: Также не помешает посмотреть `pgrep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> владельца этого процесса, аргументы с которыми был запущен этот процесс, группу владельца этого процесса

для процесс**а** номер *5059*:

```
$ ps -o user,args,group -p 5059
```

для процесс**ов**, выполняющих файл с именем *firefox*:

```
$ ps -o user,args,group -C firefox
```

> и т.д.

см. секцию *STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS* в `man ps`.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, если есть права root.

```
~# find /proc/5059 -type f -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 cat
```

Выведет всю "сырую" информацию о процессе.

```
~# cat /proc/5059/cmdline
```

Покажет какая команда была запущена в этом процессе, с полным путем до неё.

```
~# find /proc/[0-9]* -type f -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 grep "firefox"
```

Пройтись по всем процессам и найти файлы, где фигурирует firefox (активное использование философии UNIX).

Утилита **ps** формирует вывод как раз из псевдо файловой системы /proc.

```
~# strace ps 2>&1 | grep "open" | grep -oP "(?<=open\(\")/[a-z]+/" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
584 /proc/
  9 /usr/
  1 /sys/
  1 /etc/
```

Часто использую в рабочем процессе.

```
~$ ps aux | grep [f]irefox                                                     
sharlat+  2736  1.0  4.5 3659672 735104 tty2   Sl+  Jun29  89:31 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox

To see every process on the system
   using BSD syntax:
      ps ax
      ps axu
```

- grep [f]irefox - хак, убрать из поиска процесс grep.

**Ссылки**

- https://github.com/Hellseher/cix/blob/master/spices/cix-procps-ng.org
- http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/proc/fs-proc.html

Comment: `man pgrep`, наверное, поможет.

Comment: @0andriy pgrep и того же пакета, что и ps, уменьшает цепочку. Удобно использовать для поиска процессов пользователя с ключем -u. Помогает при удалении аккаунтов.

Comment: @Hellseher спасибо вам за подробное описание! Подскажите, а можно ли с помощью команды top изменить приоритет процесса?

Comment: @striker92. почитайте про nice

Comment: @Hellseher nice, renice я знаю. Хотел через top. видимо нельзя. Спасибо.

Comment: @striker92 top для мониторинга, нп сколько я знаю. ulimit -a тоже контролирует приоритеты